# Reference pixels vs percentage with min height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating a standard dashboard with bootstrap. I need to make sure that the tiles scale properly In both high res and low res and in large screens ,mobile and retina displays. I tried using percentage with min height and. But I ended up using lot of break points. Is this the right approach or should I use px for layout. Many examples in github seems to use px. Thanks in advance

**Note**
I did find similar questions on stack overflow but they specifically didn't deal with min height and percentages.

Comment: Do you have an example or some code for us to look at?

Comment: I am asking about using just px for layout (reference px) instead of ℅